# Dynamic web project deployment error in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, server, localhost, hana

I created a dynamic web project in eclipse Luna. IMHO all settings are correct for server runtime .

I am using SAP HANA Java EE 6 Web Profile SDK [SAP HANA TOOLS](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#cloud) and JDK 7 with Eclipse Luna .

When I click a project node -> run as -> run on server -> JAVA WEB EE Profile (server name), it starts server but it doesn't deploy the web page.

In console it gives message as

> ```
> java version "1.7.0_71"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
> ```
>
> C:\Users\xyz\workspace\Servers\Java EE 6 Web Profile Server-config>`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java" -server -javaagent:"C:\Users\xyz\WORKSP~1\Servers\JAVAEE~1\lib\openejb-javaagent_4.5.2.jar"  -XX:ErrorFile="C:\Users\xyz\WORKSP~1\Servers\JAVAEE~1\log\error.log" -XX:HeapDumpPath="C:\Users\xyz\WORKSP~1\Servers\JAVAEE~1\log\heap_dump.hprof" "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" "-XX:+DisableExplicitGC" "-Xms512m" "-Xmx1024m" "-XX:PermSize=256M" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256M" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1717" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" "-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6" "-DuseNaming=osgi" "-Dosgi.install.area=." "-Djava.io.tmpdir=./work/tmp" "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=lib/endorsed" "-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.exclusiveInstallation=false" "-Dcom.sap.core.process=ljs_node" "-Declipse.ignoreApp=true" "-Dosgi.noShutdown=true" "-Dosgi.framework.activeThreadType=normal" "-Dosgi.embedded.cleanupOnSave=true" "-Dosgi.usesLimit=30" "-Djava.awt.headless=true" "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1" "-Dhttp.proxyHost=172.30.0.14" "-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128" "-Dhttps.proxyHost=172.30.0.14" "-Dhttps.proxyPort=3128" "-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.local|<local>" -classpath "C:\Users\xyz\WORKSP~1\Servers\JAVAEE~1\lib\openejb-javaagent_4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\xyz\WORKSP~1\Servers\JAVAEE~1\lib\org.eclipse.virgo.nano.authentication_3.6.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xyz\WORKSP~1\Servers\JAVAEE~1\lib\org.eclipse.virgo.nano.shutdown_3.6.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xyz\WORKSP~1\Servers\JAVAEE~1\lib\org.eclipse.virgo.util.env_3.6.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\xyz\WORKSP~1\Servers\JAVAEE~1\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120308-1358.jar"  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main  -console -dev "file:C:/Users/xyz/workspace/Servers/Java EE 6 Web Profile Server-config/configuration/dev.properties"`
>
> osgi>

And in progress window it shows publishing to the server name ...

then it starts browser.

In browser it doesn't show anything i.e. empty page is displayed

- [EDIT: link broken] [image: log file]

But some times it works i.e. Web page is displayed in browser with contents

- [EDIT: link broken] [image: log file]

How to resolve this error?

Event log file:

- [EDIT: link broken] [image: Event log file]

Sometimes log files contains an error message about visual C++ , it gives error message visual C++  is not installed but in my system x86 and x64 2010 visual C++ are installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing dependencies. Your setup will display web pages, but won't talk to SAP at all. For example, in the error log that you first provide a link to, it says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load the JCo native library. (exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: JCo initialization failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sapjco3 in java.library.path)
```

And:

```
Root exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load the JCo native library. (exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: JCo initialization failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sapjco3 in java.library.path)
```

In the log you link last, it says, just before shutdown initiated:

```
[2015-01-13 23:55:24.806] pool-3-thread-1              <DS0000W> Failed to satisfy declarative service component 'com.sap.core.jpaas.security.utils' from origin bundle 'com.sap.core.jpaas.security.utils_1.4.18.rt2 [62]'.
```

And also:

```
[2015-01-14 12:36:52.206] pool-3-thread-1              <DS0000W> Failed to satisfy declarative service component 'com.sap.core.connectivity.local.destinations.DestinationFactory' from origin bundle 'com.sap.core.connectivity.local.destinations_0.9.141.rt2 [39]'.
```

You'll want to fix those by importing the appropriate library/libraries. See: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/707c54872c1b5ae10000000a42189c/frameset.htm

Comment: See the first line of my answer. You'll see webpages, but won't be able to talk to SAP (JCo is the SAP connector).

Comment: I don't have SAP marketplace UID also i can't get.do we have any other solution ?